# Is node_modules folder still needed after Laravel Mix compiled the assets?

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, node-modules, laravel-mix

`node_modules` folder is quite large in term of size. I wonder if we can delete it after Laravel Mix compile everything? Sure, I tried it before (install `jquery`) and then delete node_modules folder after Laravel Mix compiled everything. My `jquery` code still running and there's no error at all. So is it okay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, you can remove it after run:

```
npm run production
```

after run this command all necessary codes will save in app.js

and when need node_modules you can download them again with :

```
npm install
```

Comment: So I just need `node_modules` when I install a new package? Is it equal to all package? I think just because it works in `jquery` it doesn't mean that it will work for others

Comment: when you use vuejs or react as front-end, every time that you change the code you should compile and you need the node_modules but if you just use jquery or  bootstrap js or ... and write your code in script tag or sperate js file after compile you can remove the node_modules because the laravel-mix will bundle all necessary codes in app.js file

Answer (score 6):

You should never commit your `node_modules` folder to git. That would take forever. Just commit `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

However, you wouldn't want to have to re-install them everytime you build your code.  I checked a large project and the total size is `310 M`. What situation do you have where you can't keep that in place?

To directly answer your question, Laravel will *never* run code from the `node_modules` folder, all of the code used from there is compiled into `app.js`, so it is safe to delete if you had to.

Comment: So I just need node_modules when I install a new package (and run `npm run production` command)?

Comment: @Adrian like i said, code from `node_modules` is ONLY used during `npm run prod` - no packages will have a problem if you delete it.

Comment: yep. I edited my comment. So if I need a new package or compile a new one, is there any way to avoid installing `node_modules` (after delete it) again?

Comment: @Adrian no. you need it whenever you compile your code, and if you add a new package you will have to re-compile your code.  It is not a best practice to delete `node_modules`.

Comment: so technically it will be better if I just let it stay in my development machine, right?

Comment: @Adrian if you add your `dist` folder to git, then you always run `npm run prod` and add your new assets to git whenever you update your app, you never have to run `npm install` on production. So yes you can do it that way.  I personally don't commit the `dist` folder, i prefer to run `npm install && npm run prod` on my production server after new code is pushed.